# draggable div without jquery UI cant drag well

Tags: jquery, html, movable

I have this code:

***jQuery:***

```
var mouseDown=false;
var lastPositionX;
var lastPositionY;
var newX;
var newY;
var lastPositionLeft;
var lastPositionTop;
var newLeft;
var newTop;
    $("#insideMap").on("mousedown",function(){
        mouseDown=true;
        lastPositionX=e.pageX;
        lastPositionY=e.pageY;
    });
    $("#insideMap").on("mouseup",function(u){
        mouseDown=false;
    });
    $("#insideMap").on("mouseleave",function(){
        mouseDown=false;
    });
    $("#insideMap").on("mousemove",function(n){
        if (mouseDown){
            mouseDown = true; // mantain the boolean to prevent mouseleave trigger
            newX=n.pageX-lastPositionX;
            newY=n.pageY-lastPositionY;
            lastPositionLeft=$("#insideMap").position().left;
            lastPositionTop=$("#insideMap").position().top;
            newLeft=newX+lastPositionLeft;
            newTop=newY+lastPositionTop;
            $("#insideMap").css({"left":newLeft,"top":newTop});
            lastPositionX=n.pageX;
            lastPositionY=n.pageY;
        }
    });
```

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/SkWeX/3/

but something is still bad :( it doesnt work well, it is still lagging,
 can you help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:) the browser wants sometimes to drag your image (bg), you need to prevent this!

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/SkWeX/6/)*

Just add this to your `#insideMap` element's CSS:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

And this code is all you need:

```
var mouseDown=false,
    posX   = 0,
    posY   = 0,
    innerX = 0,
    innerY = 0;

$("#insideMap").on("mousedown",function(e){
    innerX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    innerY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    mouseDown= true;
}).on("mouseup",function(){
    mouseDown=false;
});

$(document).on("mousemove",function(e){    
    if (mouseDown){
        var m = {  x: e.pageX-innerX,  y: e.pageY-innerY };        
        $('#insideMap').css({ left: m.x, top: m.y });       
    }
});
```

Some explanation:

Your code is slow cause on **any** registered mousemovement (and there are many) you are recalculating the element position. Wrong.

- I grab the mouse position inside the element on click vars `innerX` and `innerX`
- On mousemove I just move the `CSS element position` to the actual mouse position (you guess right: ) but minus the position where the element was clicked (innerX, innerY) (to prevent the element jump to mouse position)  .

Comment: oh, very good :) thanks for it,http://jsfiddle.net/SkWeX/4/, but i think it is still a little bit lagging

Comment: @user1477829 P.S: do you really want that the mouseleave triggers the mouseDown (to false)? cause if you fast-reposition your element at some point your cursor will be faster than the element position and the mouseleave will trigger!

Comment: @user1477829 I reedited my answer and created a better code. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks! *'...I correct your answer'* What was wrong with my answer?